# How to resolve Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, crash, tflite, yolov4

I try to use a .tflite file in my Android Studio Application. This model is able to detect shape in an image. The objective is to create boundings boxes around the shape of interest. For that I made this programm :

```
    private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile() throws IOException {
        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = getContext().getAssets().openFd("yolov4.tflite");
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
        FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
        long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
        long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
        MappedByteBuffer modelBuffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, 
declaredLength);

        if (modelBuffer != null) {
            System.out.println("Model load with success.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error during loading model.");
        }

        return modelBuffer;
    }

    // Method to do the inference
    public void createBoundingBox(Bitmap image){

        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        Bitmap resizedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, image.getConfig());
        try {
            MappedByteBuffer tfliteModel = loadModelFile();
            // Creates inputs for reference.
            TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 416, 416, 3}, DataType.FLOAT32);

            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = convertBitmapToByteBuffer(resizedImage);

            inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);

            Interpreter tflite = new Interpreter(tfliteModel);

            Object[] inputs = {inputFeature0.getBuffer()};
            Map<Integer, Object> outputs = new HashMap<>();
            TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 416, 416, 3}, DataType.FLOAT32);
            outputs.put(0, outputFeature0.getBuffer());

            tflite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputs, outputs);

            List<Detection> detections = processModelOutputs(outputFeature0);

            //draw the bounding box
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resizedImage);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(2);

            for(Detection detection : detections){
                float left = (detection.centerX - detection.width/2)*resizedImage.getWidth();
                float top = (detection.centerY - detection.height/2)*resizedImage.getHeight();
                float bottom = (detection.centerY + detection.height/2)*resizedImage.getHeight();
                float right = (detection.centerX + detection.width/2)*resizedImage.getWidth();
                canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
            }

            imageView.setImageBitmap(resizedImage);

            // Releases model resources if no longer used.
            tflite.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Not connected to the model");
        }
    }
```

```
private ByteBuffer convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap){
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*416*416*3);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        int[] intValues = new int[imageSize*imageSize];
        bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, 416, 0, 0, 416, 416);
        for (int i = 0; i<imageSize; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<imageSize; j++) {
                int val = intValues[i*416+j];
                byteBuffer.putFloat(((val>>16)&0xFF)*(1.f/255));
                byteBuffer.putFloat(((val>>8)&0xFF)*(1.f/255));
                byteBuffer.putFloat((val&0xFF)*(1.f/255));
            }
        }

        return byteBuffer;
    }
```

However the error :

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)" appears for this line : "outputs.put(0, outputFeature0.getBuffer());
```

I tried to use the java code of the yolov4.tflite model

```
try {
    Yolov4 model = Yolov4.newInstance(context);

    // Creates inputs for reference.
    TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 416, 416, 3}, DataType.FLOAT32);
    inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);

    // Runs model inference and gets result.
    Yolov4.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
    TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

    // Releases model resources if no longer used.
    model.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Handle the exception
}
```

But the same error appeared for the the line

`TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 416, 416, 3}, DataType.FLOAT32);`

Comment: Fixed: I decided to create another detection model with Tensorflow and convert it into .tflite. I am now able to use this model in my android app. In my opinion my Yolov4 model was to complex to be used by my android app. It is also possible that I made a mistake during the conversion from darknet format to tflite format.